# PHP - How do I count the number of times you echoed a text but put it at the top?

Tags: php, function

I am trying to count how many times I echoed a text but I want to display the number (count) at the top of the page.

I have an array of data called transactions. I want to echo all the transactions but also include the total number of transactions at the top of the page like this:

"10 transactions found!

Transaction 1 ....

Transaction 2 ...

....

Transaction 10 ..."

I have this below but the issue is that the "number of transactions found" will be echoed after all the transactions data but I want it at the top".

```
function count_transactions($array_transactions) {
  if(isset($array_transactions)){
    $count = 0;
    foreach($array_transactions['data']['txs'] as $value){
      echo "<p>Transactions id: " . $value['txid'] . "</p>";
      $count++;
    }
    echo $count . "transactions found!";
  }
}
```

I was thinking that I can use array_push() to push all transactions data into an array and then echo each value in the array after the count is completed. However, this way I would need another foreach loop which will slow down the page if a lot of data is in the transaction array. Is there an easier way to echo $count at the top without using another foreach loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would simplify things to just use the `count()` function.

```
function count_transactions($array_transactions) {
    if (isset($array_transactions['data']['txs'])) {

        // Count goes at the top
        echo count($array_transactions['data']['txs']) . "transactions found!";

        // Then the list
        foreach($array_transactions['data']['txs'] as $value){
            echo "<p>Transactions id: " . $value['txid'] . "</p>";
        }
    }
}
```

Also, when you check `isset`, it seems better to check that the specific sub-array you're about to iterate is set. `$array_transactions` will always be set - it's a required function argument.

Answer (score 2):

Store the text in a variable and echo after the loop is done

```
function count_transactions($array_transactions) {
  if(isset($array_transactions)){
    $count = 0;
    $text = "";
    foreach($array_transactions['data']['txs'] as $value){
      $text .= "<p>Transactions id: " . $value['txid'] . "</p>";
      $count++;
    }
    echo $count . "transactions found!";
    echo $text;
  }
}
```

Depending on what the array looks like you may be able to use implode, array_column and count.

```
function count_transactions($array_transactions) {
    if(isset($array_transactions)){
        echo count($array_transactions['data']['txs']).  "transactions found!";
        echo "<p>Transactions id: " . implode("</p><p>Transactions id: ", array_column($array_transactions, "txid")) . "</p>";
    }
}
```

But this will only work if the array is uniformed.